# How to add Html file into cakephp App?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2, cakephp-2.0

I have a html file and want to add it into cakephp App, I know that I　can add css and image files into the Webroot folder, and rewrite the postfix of .html to .ctp, but how to use it in my cakephp app ,just like I can visit it just like http://localhost/users/login in IE?

Answer (score 2):

You can place it directly in your app/webroot/ folder. It will be accessible at the URL `http://localhost/filename.html`.

Comment: Yes, I can visit it , but In this html some place will show using elements by php just like app\views\layouts\admin_default.ctp , and how to do with it , thank you very much!

Comment: I think maybe using MVC , but How to do with it ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your HTML file is called myfile.html.

Copy myfile.html to app/views/pages/myfile.ctp

You will now be able to view the page at http://localhost/pages/myfile